# Serving an OpenSearch `application/x-suggestions+json` through a service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker, opensearch

Been trying in Chrome to get my `application/x-suggestions+json` file get recognized when it's served through a service worker, but no matter what I do it seems to just totally bypass it. Am I missing something or is this actually impossible?

Comment: Can you paste code, please?

Comment: @Salva: What code do you want to see pasted? I am using the Google made `sw-toolbox` to serve the suggestions with a standard `new Response(JSON.stringify(suggestions))` and I have the `<Url>` tag in my `opensearch.xml` to link to the file.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the response, you must specify the headers to include the proper content type. You can do it by using the [init dictionary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response) for the Response constructor. For instance:

```
var response = new Response(JSON.stringify(suggestions), {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-suggestions+json' }
});
```